# Python and LXML: changing attributes of different contiguous elements if certain conditions are met

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I have to process XML files with structures such as the following:

```
<tok tag1="blah1" tag2="blah2" tag3="blah3">TEXT1</tok> 
<tok tag1="blahA" tag2="blahB" tag3="blahC">TEXT2</tok>
<tok tag1="blahX" tag2="blahY" tag3="blahZ">TEXT3</tok>
<tok tag1="blah1" tag2="blah2" tag3="blah3">TEXTA</tok> 
<tok tag1="blahA" tag2="blahB" tag3="blahC">TEXTB</tok>
<tok tag1="blahX" tag2="blahY" tag3="blahZ">TEXTC</tok>
<tok tag1="blahA" tag2="blahB" tag3="blahC">TEXT7</tok>
<tok tag1="blahX" tag2="blahY" tag3="blahZ">TEXTX</tok>
```

I want to be able to change the values in attributes from more than one element for specific sequences of elements whenever certain conditions are met.

For instance, in the previous example document I'd like to change the value of attribute 'tag1' in the first element of the sequence to "changed" and the value of the same attribute in the following element to "changed2" if the sequence of elements have the sequence of atomic values 'TEXTA', 'TEXTB' and 'TEXTC'. So, the output would have to be:

```
<tok tag1="blah1" tag2="blah2" tag3="blah3">TEXT1</tok> 
<tok tag1="blahA" tag2="blahB" tag3="blahC">TEXT2</tok>
<tok tag1="blahX" tag2="blahY" tag3="blahZ">TEXT3</tok>
<tok tag1="changed" tag2="blah2" tag3="blah3">TEXTA</tok> 
<tok tag1="changed2" tag2="blahB" tag3="blahC">TEXTB</tok>
<tok tag1="blahX" tag2="blahY" tag3="blahZ">TEXTC</tok>
<tok tag1="blahA" tag2="blahB" tag3="blahC">TEXT7</tok>
<tok tag1="blahX" tag2="blahY" tag3="blahZ">TEXTX</tok>
```

Right now I know how to do this only when the modification would affect only one element.

```
for el in root.xpath('//tok[text()="TEXTA"][following-sibling::tok[1][text()="TEXTB"]][following-sibling::tok[2][text()="TEXTC"]]':
   el.set('tag1', 'changed')
```

I've read the documentation and tutorials I've found for the XPath syntax but I cannot figure out how to add the instructions for the modifications to affect also other elements following or preceding the one that is specified  as 'el' in the code. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this time try it this way:

```
for el in root.xpath('//tok[.="TEXTB"][preceding-sibling::tok[1][.="TEXTA"]][following-sibling::tok[1][.="TEXTC"]]'):
    el.set('tag1', 'changed2')
    el.xpath('preceding-sibling::tok[1]')[0].set('tag1', 'changed')
print(etree.tostring(root).decode())
```

and the output should be your expected output.

Comment: Actually, can I ask you a question? This works but I would like to understand a bit better how. What does the '[0]' do? There is already an index [1] in ::tok[1]. I don't understand what the role of this '[0]' is. 

I have actually tried to do it like the following and it also works. But I still need the '[0]'. 

for el in doc.xpath('//tok[.="TEXTA"][following-sibling::tok[1][.="TEXTB"]][following-sibling::tok[2][.="TEXTC"]]'):
    el.set('tag1', 'changed')
    el.xpath('following-sibling::tok[1]')[0].set('tag1', 'changed222')

Comment: @jfontana xpath returns a list, even if the list contains only one element (as it does in this case); in order to select that element and modify it, you need to specify that element - that's where `[0]` comes in (indicating the first - and only - element in the list returned by the expression). Also remember that python counts from 0 (so the first element is `[0]`), while xpath counts from 1 (so the first element is `[1]`, as in `preceding-sibling::tok[1]`). Annoying, but eventually you get used to it....